# Can anyone help me create the table below?

Tags: tables, multirow

I try to use \multirow to create the table below, but it failed. Making the "unit" below the item causes table creation difficult for me.
Anyone can help me out?
[image]

Comment: Why don't you give us at least the data and the code you have produced so far?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that using `\multirow` improves the look of the header cells -- quite the opposite, actually. The big gap between the first and second group of three columns seems excessive; you may get a better overall effect by trimming the `\cmidrule`s to leave a modest visual gap. Finally, since the data are numeric, you may want to consider using the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) instead of the basic `c` column type.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of Groups A and B}\label{AB}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{7}{S[table-format=1.3]}@{}}
  \toprule
  No. & A & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Group A} &\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Group B}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
  \cmidrule(l){6-8}
  &&A&B&C&A&B&C\\
  &{(unit)}&{(unit)}&&{(unit)}&{(unit)}&&{(unit)}\\
  \midrule
  1 & 0.751 & 0.498 & 0.706 & 0.823 & 0.439 & 0.490 & 0.276\\
  2 & 0.255 & 0.960 & 0.032 & 0.695 & 0.382 & 0.446 & 0.680\\
  3 & 0.506 & 0.340 & 0.277 & 0.317 & 0.766 & 0.646 & 0.655\\
  4 & 0.699 & 0.585 & 0.046 & 0.950 & 0.795 & 0.709 & 0.163\\
  5 & 0.891 & 0.224 & 0.097 & 0.034 & 0.187 & 0.755 & 0.119\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Table Construction:

Code:

```
\documentclass[table]{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.90\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rrrrrrrr}
\hline \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{No} & \multirow{4}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Group A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Group B}\\
                                 & \multirow{4}{*}{(unit)}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{-------------------------------}  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{-------------------------------} \\
                               &     & A & \quad \quad     B & C & A &\quad \quad B &C \\
                               &     &  (unit) & &(unit)  &  (unit) & &(unit)\\
\hline

1 & 0.751 & 0.498 & 0.706 & 0.823 & 0.439 & 0.490 & 0.276 \\
2 & 0.255 & 0.960 & 0.032 & 0.695 & 0.382 & 0.446 & 0.680 \\
3&  0.506 & 0.340 & 0.277 & 0.317 & 0.766 & 0.646 & 0.655 \\
4&  0.699 & 0.585 & 0.046 & 0.950 & 0.795 & 0.709 &0.163 \\
5 & 0.891 & 0.224 & 0.097 & 0.034 & 0.187 & 0.755 & 0.119\\
\hline \hline

\end{tabular*}
\caption{Comparison of Group A and B}
\label{tab:compr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seams that I get a better solution. See below

Comment: If you're going to use `------...` to create long lines, be sure to use a number of dashes that's an exact multiple of three. Otherwise you end up with a bunch of em-dashes followed by either a simple dash (as in the screenshot) or an en-dash. That said, either `\cline` or `\cmidrule` would seem to provide a more natural way for obtaining the lines in question.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[table]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of Group A and B}\label{AB}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
  \toprule
  \multirow{3}[4]{*}{No.} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Group A} & &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Group B}\\
  \cmidrule(r){3-5}
  \cmidrule(r){7-9}
  &A&A&\multirow{2}[4]{*}{B}&C&&A&\multirow{2}[4]{*}{B}&C\\
  &(unit)&(unit)&&(unit)&&(unit)&&(unit)\\
  \midrule
  1 & 0.751 & 0.498 & 0.706 & 0.823 && 0.439 & 0.490 & 0.276 \\
  2 & 0.255 & 0.960 & 0.032 & 0.695 && 0.382 & 0.446 & 0.680 \\
  3 &  0.506 & 0.340 & 0.277 & 0.317 && 0.766 & 0.646 & 0.655 \\
  4 &  0.699 & 0.585 & 0.046 & 0.950 && 0.795 & 0.709 &0.163 \\
  5 & 0.891 & 0.224 & 0.097 & 0.034 && 0.187 & 0.755 & 0.119\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please use the '{}' button to format your code as code. also I would consider keeping all the column names on the same row, simply leaving blanks on the unit row where none is necessary - and i have seen that done with additional single-column `cmidrule`s between unit and column name..

Comment: The placement of the `B` column headers strikes me as bordering on the hideous. Loading the `multicol` and `caption` packages isn't needed for this MWE, is it? What is the purpose of the `table` option in the `\documentclass` command? The `[H]` location specifier doesn't do anything unless the `float` package is loaded as well.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the pointing out the problems.

Comment: @greyshade: Thanks for your suggestion. I will keep all the column names on the same row. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

A different alignment for the first rows, an automatic numbering of rows and a  slight simplification of code with the `makecell` or `stackengine` packages (no multirows):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{tc}

\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\newcounter{rowno}
\newcommand\emptycell{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}}
\providecommand*\No{N\textsuperscript{\kern0.06em\underline{\kern-0.06em o\kern-0.068em}}}
\begin{document}
With \texttt{makecell}: 
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\caption{Comparison of Groups A and B}\label{AB}
\begin{tabular}{>{\refstepcounter{rowno}\,\therowno}c*{7}{S[table-format=1.3]}}%{}
\toprule
\emptycell & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Group A} &\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Group B}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{\\\No}} & {\thead{A\\}}& {\thead{A\\(unit)}} &{ \thead{B\\}} &{\thead{C\\(unit)}} & {\thead{A\\(unit)}}& {\thead{B}} & {\thead{C\\(unit)}}\\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){1-8}
\addlinespace[1.2ex]
& 0.751 & 0.498 & 0.706 & 0.823 & 0.439 & 0.490 & 0.276\\
& 0.255 & 0.960 & 0.032 & 0.695 & 0.382 & 0.446 & 0.680\\
& 0.506 & 0.340 & 0.277 & 0.317 & 0.766 & 0.646 & 0.655\\
& 0.699 & 0.585 & 0.046 & 0.950 & 0.795 & 0.709 & 0.163\\
& 0.891 & 0.224 & 0.097 & 0.034 & 0.187 & 0.755 & 0.119\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vskip 1cm
With \texttt{stackengine}:
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\caption{Comparison of Groups A and B}\label{AB}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\refstepcounter{rowno}\,\therowno}c*{7}{c}}%{}S[table-format=1.3]
\toprule
\emptycell & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Group A} &\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Group B}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\stackunder{}{\No}} & {A} & {\stackunder{A}{(unit)}} & {B} &
{\stackunder{C}{(unit)}} & {\stackunder{A}{(unit)}}& {B} & {\stackunder{C}{(unit)}}\\
\addlinespace
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){1-8}
\addlinespace[1.2ex]
& 0.751 & 0.498 & 0.706 & 0.823 & 0.439 & 0.490 & 0.276\\
& 0.255 & 0.960 & 0.032 & 0.695 & 0.382 & 0.446 & 0.680\\
& 0.506 & 0.340 & 0.277 & 0.317 & 0.766 & 0.646 & 0.655\\
& 0.699 & 0.585 & 0.046 & 0.950 & 0.795 & 0.709 & 0.163\\
& 0.891 & 0.224 & 0.097 & 0.034 & 0.187 & 0.755 & 0.119\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]